# passing a function in a program has a struct c++

Tags: c++, struct

i'm struggling in solving this problem regardless of its simplicity but i don't know where is the exact error.

this problem is a practice on structures and it requires from the user to input 2 students' names and their ages and returns the name of the older person using struct and a function for returning the name of the student.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct student{
    string name;
    int age;
};

student getOlder(student s1, student s2);

int main()
{
    student s1, s2, Max;

    cout << "Enter the first sudent's name" << endl;
    getline(cin, s1.name);

    cout << "Enter the first sudent's age" << endl;
    cin >> s1.age;

    cout << "Enter the second sudent's name" << endl;
    getline(cin, s2.name);

    cout << "Enter the second sudent's age" << endl;
    cin >> s2.age;
    Max = getOlder(s1, s2);
    cout << Max << " is the older student " << endl;
}

student getOlder(student s1, student s2)
{
    if (s1.age > s2.age){
        cout << s1.name << endl;
    }
    cout << s2.name << endl;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the older student:

```
student getOlder(student s1, student s2)
{
  if (s1.age > s2.age)
  {
     return s1;
  }
  return s2;
}
```

Also, since you are not changing the content of `s1` or `s2`, they should be passed as constant references:

```
student getOlder(const student& s1, const student& s2)
{
 // ...
}
```

**Edit 1: Overloading comparison operators**
Optionally, you can add methods for comparison:

```
struct student
{
  std::string name;
  unsigned int age; // int implies age can be negative.
  bool operator>(const student& s2)
  {
     return age > s2.age;
  }
}
```

This allows you to write things like:

```
if (s1 > s2)
{
  cout << "Student " << s1.name << " is older than " << s2.name << endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm really thankful, but I have a little question, the compiler now highlighting the operands before the veriable " Max" in the line ""  cout << Max << " is the older student " << endl; " as there is no operator matches these operands. what does this mean and how to correct this error?

Comment: You have not provided an overload of `operator<<` for your structure, so `cout` doesn't know how to output it.  Either overload `operator<<` or output the members individually.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `result` in your final function was never declared. You can set it equal to `s1` or `s2` during the if/else:

```
student result;
if(s1.age>s2.age){
    result=s1;
}else{
    result=s2;
}
return result
```

Or you could skip over the `result` part and just return the student:

```
if (s1.age > s2.age)
{
    return (s1);
}
    return(s2);
```

Comment: I'm really thankful, but I have a little question, the compiler now highlighting the operands before the veriable " Max" in the line ""  cout << Max << " is the older student " << endl; " as there is no operator matches these operands. what does this mean and how to correct this error?

Comment: This is happening because of printing a name, you're trying to print the student itself. Just replace "Max" with "Max.name" and it should work.